# In the sentence "I was made to accept the proposal" is the verb "made" in passive voice? and how would it be in active?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice, active-vs-passive

I cannot figure out if it's a passive structure.

Comment: It's certainly passive, and the active would be "They/he/[name] made me accept the proposal".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a passive construction. It is in the past tense (indicated by the finite verb "was"). To convert to an active sentence  Insert a "by" phrase:

> [I] was made to accept the proposal [by someone]

Then re-arrange. Put the "By" person as the subject and the subject "I" as the object "me".

> Someone made me accept the proposal.